# How to convert and import Arc Shapefile from Zillow into an elastic search database?

Tags: elasticsearch, arcgis, shapefile, geo

I'd like to create a service based on Zillow's neighborhood data, and I need to convert the Arc Shapefile format into data(json?) that I can import into ElasticSearch as a geo-shape.

Data:

http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm

ElasticSearch (destination of the data)

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-shape-type.html

Are there any free tools that I can use, preferably in node.js or .net that convert the files to json - or import directly into a more mainstream database?  I could just use some help getting the raw data out of the shape files and then I can parse and load the data myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so i can use ogr2ogr from the GDAL framework to convert the data from shapefiles into json which I can then export to elasticsearch.

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs crs:84 NY.geojson ZillowNeighborhoods-NY.shp
```

see http://geojson.org/ and GDAL ogr2ogr

Comment: GDAL also supports Elasticsearch directly, no need to use the geojson as an intermediary.